# Scanning through rows of dataframe for particular vaule

Tags: python, pandas

I am new using pandas 
I have a following dataframe in the form of **Attribute** and its corresponding **Value** spread across the sheet

```
    attr1   val1   attr2    val2    attr3   val3    attr4   val4
0   APPL    abc    DES      tool    comp    Wind        
1   APPL    ABC    DES      tool    comp    Wind        
2   Serial  f1     APPL     MAC     des     Service     
3   Serial  f1     category male    APPL    MAC      DES    tool
4   Serial  f1     APPL     abc     DES     Service     
5   APPL    ABC    DES      Service
```

from the dataframe i have to extract value for Attribute = APPL and Attribute = DES and store it in another dataframe in the following manner

```
    Value1           value2
    Value for appl   Value for des
0   abc              tool
1   ABC              tool
2   MAC              Service
3   MAC              tool
4   abc              Service
5   ABC              Service
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres one way do to do it

```
# For the sake of case insensitivity convert values to lower. 
# Then check if appl and des present in the dataframe .isin gives boolean mask.
# Since you want the next values shift the bool. 
mask = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x:x.str.lower()).isin(['appl','des']).T.shift().T.fillna(False)


cols ={'attr1':'AAPL','val1':'DES'}

#Sort the values based on nans , then drop the nan columns 
df[mask].apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1).dropna(1).rename(columns=cols)
```

Output :

```
  AAPL      DES
0  abc     tool
1  ABC     tool
2  MAC  Service
3  MAC     tool
4  abc  Service
5  ABC  Service
```